# Unity: Extracting content of the clipboard to a variable. GUIUtility.systemCopyBuffer

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, clipboard

In Unity (C#) I am trying to set a variable to the **contents of the clipboard**. 
This is what I have tried but it doesn't seem to work:

```
    var test = GUIUtility.systemCopyBuffer;
    print(test);
```

Am I not using it correctly? I am still a bit of a noob at Unity and I appreciate all help :)

I have looked at the documentation but can't seem to find anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get content from clipboard:

```
string content = GUIUtility.systemCopyBuffer;
```

Set content/overwrite what is in the clipboard:

```
GUIUtility.systemCopyBuffer = "My new content";
```

OR

```
string contentToSet = "My new content";
GUIUtility.systemCopyBuffer = contentToSet ;
```